# How do I check an array for multiple values in Javascript (avoid using too many "or" statements)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 select list drop downs. Select list A has 10 values (int). If a certain selection is made aka: a specific value, then I want to Select list B to be hidden. Right now I have the hiding functionality, if I use multiple "||" or statements, but this is messy and no good practice. How do I check if a specific value is chosen without using a bunch of or statements?

Current Code (working but ugly):

```
$('#status').change(function(){
            let $appStatus = $('#status').val();

        if($appStatus == 400 || $appStatus == 606 || $appStatus == 620 || $appStatus == 700 || $appStatus == 1000 || $appStatus == 1020){
          console.log(true);
          $reasonNoHire.hide()
        }else{
          console.log(false);
          $reasonNoHire.show();
        }
      });
```

Other code I have tried by always returns false

```
            //Brought back depending on what the user chooses in Selectlist A
            let $appStatus = $('#status').val();
            let valArray = [400, 606, 620, 700, 1000, 1020];

            if(valArray.includes($appStatus)){
              console.log(true);
              $reasonNoHire.hide()
            }else{
              console.log(false);
              $reasonNoHire.show();
            }
          });
```

Comment: Why would the 2nd chunk return false? Can you  `console.log($appStatus);` and see why?

Comment: Where do you want me to console.log it?

Comment: Yeah, the code looks correct. Good job being on the right track. Log $appStatus right after you declare it.

Comment: `$appStatus` would be a string and you have an array of numbers. Either convert `$appStatus` to a number or make your array only have strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `$appStatus` is a string and not a number. This happens to pass in your first example because you are using `==` instead of `===`. `Array.prototype.includes` returns false because `[400].includes('400')` is comparing a string to a number.

Answer (score 1):

`$('#status').val()` returns a string but you are comparing it against numbers. You are using [loose equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using) in the first snippet. So, it works. But, [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Return_value) uses [*Same-value-zero*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Same-value-zero_equality) algorithm to compare (Almost equal to *Strict Equality*). So, change the array to an array of strings or convert the value to a number before checking `includes`